# How can I sort dates in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting

How can I sort the dates in Perl?

```
my @dates =  ( "02/11/2009" , "20/12/2001" , "21/11/2010" );
```

I have above dates in my array . How can I sort those dates?

My date format is `dd/mm/YYYY`.

Comment: Storing dates as `YYYY/MM/DD` makes much easier. You can do whatever you want when you display them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
@dates = sort { join('', (split '/', $a)[2,1,0]) cmp join('', (split '/', $b)[2,1,0]) } @dates;
```

or using separate sorting subroutine:

```
sub mysort {
    join('', (split '/', $a)[2,1,0]) cmp join('', (split '/', $b)[2,1,0]);
}
@dates = sort mysort @dates;
```

Update: A more efficient approach is the Schwartzian Transform:

```
@dates = 
    map $_->[0],
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
    map  [ $_, join('', (split '/', $_)[2,1,0]) ], @dates;
```

Comment: Do this with a Schwartzian Transform or other cached key sort so you don't have to recompute the values every time.

Comment: And if your dates have times e.g. 29/4/2021-00:10:10 you can split on / or - using [\/\-] and join fields back using [2,1,0,3]. i.e. ```sort { join('', (split '[\/\-]', $a)[2,1,0,3]) cmp join('', (split '[\/\-]', $b)[2,1,0,3]) }```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the `YYYY/MM/DD` format better, for just this reason. It's guaranteed to sort dates properly, between `1000/01/01` and `9999/12/31`.

```
my @sorted_alt = sort map { join '/', reverse split '/', $_  } @dates;
```

If you really need it in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, you could always go for a complete [Schwartzian transform](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

```
my @sorted = map {
  join '/', reverse split '/', $_
}
sort
map {
  join '/', reverse split '/', $_ 
} @dates;
```

or

```
my @sorted = map {
  join '/', reverse @$_
}
sort { "@$a" cmp "@$b" }
map {
  [ reverse split '/', $_ ]
} @dates;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the epoch format in timestamp and sort them as numbers.  Then convert date strings output as you want. Then you are not stuck with formatting the origin strings.

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed how to do this. Can you add an example?

Answer (score 1):

Many people here argued correctly that the original format of the dates should be in yyyy-mm-dd format, but nobody has given the Perl code that can handle that case yet.  So here it is:

```
my @dates = (
    '2014-08-15',
    '2016-09-13',
    '2001-01-02',
    '1998-09-22',
    '1998-09-21',
    '1998-09-23',
    '1999-04-20',
    '2020-01-30',
);

@dates = sort {$a cmp $b} @dates;   # 1998 is the first date's year
@dates = sort {$b cmp $a} @dates;   # 2014 is the first date's year
```

Comment: Brad Gilbert's answer contains code for that case. It's just `@dates = sort @dates;`.

Comment: Ah, good point -- but I like my example because it actually works on an array of correct values (no split map magic), it shows both orders in explaining ascending versus descending, and it does not unnecessarily interpolate the sorted values.